# Why is my LINQ Expression with multiple parameters not compiling?

Tags: c#, linq, parameters, expression

I want to extend the LINQ expression (DoSomething)

```
using LinqKit; // for System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<>.Invoke()

public class Expressions
{
  public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<
    System.Func<int, int, int, int, bool>>
      DoSomething =
        (a, b, c, d) => false;
}

public class ExpressionTester
{
  public ExpressionTester()
  {
    Expressions.DoSomething.Invoke(1, 2, 3, 4);
  }
}
```

with an additional parameter but it does not compile:

```
public class Expressions
{
  public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<
    System.Func<int, int, int, int, int, bool>>
      DoSomething =
        (a, b, c, d, e) => false;
}

public class ExpressionTester
{
  public ExpressionTester()
  {
    Expressions.DoSomething.Invoke(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
  }
}

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Invoke(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[])' has some invalid arguments
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'
error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'
error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'
error CS1503: Argument 4: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'
error CS1503: Argument 5: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'
```

Is there an undocumented limitation to the number of parameters?

:edit

Thanks to the answer of an unknown author that deleted its answer 10 seconds later i see that LinqKit is compiled with .NET 3.5 whereas this caused the limitation of System.Func<> to 4 parameters.

:edit2

The suggested `Compile().Invoke()` workaround is not working in all cases in connection with queries (which i need). Thus i created a fork from the LINQKit project and added some code to support up to 16 parameters:

https://github.com/ViRuSTriNiTy/LINQKit/commit/bcca71978ef3fbb988d242463adfbc4e9cd42565

Comment: If it doesn't compile, show the error message.

Comment: Your fifth parameter suppose to be bool not int, but you are parsing int.

Comment: @cubrr i've edited the question and added the error messages.

Comment: @Jegan bool is the return type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a fifth parameter, you're binding to a different `Invoke` that the one in `LinqKit`:

```
public static TResult Invoke<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult> (
    this Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>> expr, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
{
    return expr.Compile ().Invoke (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
}
```

Note that there's not one with 5 arguments, so you end up binding to `Expression.Invoke`, which takes a parameter array of `Expression`s:

```
public static InvocationExpression Invoke(Expression expression, params Expression[] arguments) {
    return Invoke(expression, (IEnumerable<Expression>)arguments);
}
```

Luckily, you can replicate the implementation from LinqKit by just calling `Compile()` on the expression to turn it into a delegate:

```
public class ExpressionTester
{
  public ExpressionTester()
  {
    Expressions.DoSomething.Compile().Invoke(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
  }
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer as its the most comprehensible one.

Answer (score 3):

The [LinqKit 1.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) I've found on nuget (and on [github](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/Extensions.cs)) supports up to four parameters for the `Invoke`...

```
public static TResult Invoke<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>> expr, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
{
    return expr.Compile()(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
}
```

It is trivial to do it for 5 parameters based on the one with 4.

```
public static TResult Invoke<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, TResult>> expr, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
{
    return expr.Compile()(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just call `.Compile().Invoke()` instead. This code compiles:

```
public class Expressions
{
    public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<
      System.Func<int, int, int, int, int, bool>>
        DoSomething =
          (a, b, c, d, e) => false;
}

public class ExpressionTester
{
    public ExpressionTester()
    {
        Expressions.DoSomething.Compile().Invoke(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i could but i need those expressions in connection with DB queries and i cannot use compile() there.

Comment: you can see in xanatos's answer that the code you're using is doing the same thing as above.

Comment: the source code in LinqKit is literally doing `Compile().Invoke()`, so it's doing the same thing, but okay.

Comment: I had to delete my comment as today i've been facing the issue again that `Compile().Invoke()` does not always work in connection with a query. When you use it inside a `select new { .... }` block it works but try to use it in lets say a `where ...` condition and you will get an exception `DoSomething has no SQL translation`.

Comment: That will always be the case. You will always have to craft your queries properly such that they can be converted to SQL, whether they are built dynamically like this or not